# Multiple SQL counts into single result set

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

Howsit everyone

I am trying to do something i think is impossible on MYSQL.

We have a very large database where we pull production reports from for our products created. At the moment we run multiple queries to get these results and then transfer the data manually to a table before it gets sent off to whomever needs the reports.

is there an easier way to do this. IE a single query.

Examples of the queries i run

```
a. SELECT count(id) from ProductA_T where created between '<date>' and '<date>' and productstatus = "<successful>";
b. SELECT count(id) from ProductB_T where created between '<date>' and '<date>' and productstatus = "<successful>";
c. SELECT count(id) from ProductC_T where created between '<date>' and '<date>' and productstatus = "<successful>";
```

Example of the result im looking for

1. ProductA      ProductB         ProductC
2. 500           500              500

Comment: Do you only have 3 products?

Comment: I actually have 7 different products with multiple product statusses i have to check. If i can get the basics of the query running the way i need it to the rest would be easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put everything into a Select clause, like this:

```
Select
(SELECT count(id) from ProductA_T where created between '<date>' and '<date>' and productstatus = "<successful>") as CountA
(SELECT count(id) from ProductB_T where created between '<date>' and '<date>' and productstatus = "<successful>") as CountB
(SELECT count(id) from ProductC_T where created between '<date>' and '<date>' and productstatus = "<successful>") as CountC
```

That way you'll have an input like this:

- CountA CountB CountC
- 500    500    500

You can later add more Count easily

Answer (score 0):

You could use UNION ALL:

```
SELECT 'ProductA', count(id) from ProductA_T where created between '<date>' and '<date>' and productstatus = "<successful>"
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ProductB', count(id) from ProductB_T where created between '<date>' and '<date>' and productstatus = "<successful>"
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ProductC', count(id) from ProductC_T where created between '<date>' and '<date>' and productstatus = "<successful>";
```

Of course, you can just duplicate the select for other 4 products or any amount you wish ;-)

Comment: Sorry Im posting from my mobile :-/

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use Stored Procedure

```
Create StoredProcedure SP_Name_1
As
Beign
Declare @id1 int,@id2 int,@id3 int;
SELECT @id1 = count(id) from ProductA_T where created between '<date>' and '<date>' and productstatus = "<successful>";
SELECT @id2 = count(id) from ProductB_T where created between '<date>' and '<date>' and productstatus = "<successful>";
SELECT @id2 = count(id) from ProductC_T where created between '<date>' and '<date>' and productstatus = "<successful>";

select  @id1 as ProductA ,@id2 as ProductB ,@id3 as ProductC
End
```

Thanks,
Taha

Comment: Won't scale for `n` amount of products.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO - OP indicated in comments that s/he has about 7 such tables.

Comment: @PM77-1 *About* is an excellent word for programming requirements.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO if u see the time of comments is approximately same, furthermore creator also updated the comments which also take extra time. Every answer is not scale for n amount here.

Comment: Stored Procedure are the optimize way for doing this task